# How to change grub boot menu on a (formerly) live linux system?

Tags: boot, live-usb, uefi, syslinux, tails-os

So I converted a usb live linux install (Tails) from USB to virtualbox using `VBoxManage convertfromraw`.

For it to boot in virtualbox, I need to remove one thing from the boot commandline (`live-media=removable`).

This option is not in the usual /etc/default/grub or grub.d locations.  I did find it in:

`/lib/live/mount/medium/syslinux/live.cfg.`

I'm not sure how that ends up in the grub commandline.   In fact, there is nothing in /boot/grub except unicode.pf2, so I think there is some other mechanism going on here.

This is EFI, also.    I'm reluctant to run `update-grub` in case this command line is being put together in a different manner.

Comment: Your converted live disk uses Syslinux.  See [How do I Configure SYSLINUX?](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=SYSLINUX#How_do_I_Configure_SYSLINUX.3F).  Edit live.cfg or create a new syslinux.cfg

Answer (score 0):

Boot it (in virtualbox) and press esc to bring up the grub menu and from there edit the command-line.

Once it's running edit the grub config and run update-grub.